# Toggle class on 1 element and remove from rest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm more of a back-end guy, but I got frustrated by this small problem related to front-end.

I have a side menu with few links.

```
<div id="sideMenu" class="vertical-menu">
    <a href="#" id="allCategories" class="active" onclick="changeClass(this)">All</a>
    <a href="#" id="fruit" onclick="changeClass(this)">Fruits</a>
    <a href="#" id="vegetables" onclick="changeClass(this)">Vegetables</a>
    <a href="#" id="fish" onclick="changeClass(this)">Fish</a>
    <a href="#" id="meat" onclick="changeClass(this)">Meats</a>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to toggle `active` class on click and remove it from another menu items

```
<script>
    function changeClass(element) {
        $('#sideMenu').each(function(){
            var theID = $(this).attr('id');
            var menuElement = document.getElementById(theID);
            menuElement.classList.remove('active')
        });
        $(element).toggleClass('active');
    }
</script>
```

I've tried few other ways and it all fails, it toggles `active` class on the new item, but it doesn't remove it from other ones.

## EDIT

I've ran into another problem.

```
 <div id="sideMenu" class="vertical-menu">
    <a href="/productsTable" id="allCategories" class="active">All</a>
    <a href="/productsTableCategory?id=1" id="fruit">Fruits</a>
    <a href="/productsTableCategory?id=2" id="vegetables">Vegetables</a>
    <a href="/productsTableCategory?id=3" id="fish">Fish</a>
    <a href="/productsTableCategory?id=4" id="meat">Meat</a>
</div>

 <script>
    $("#sideMenu a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sideMenu a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })
</script>
```

and back-end side

```
private ProductRepository productRepository;
    private ProductCategoryRepository productCategoryRepository;

@Autowired
public ProductsTableController(ProductRepository productRepository, ProductCategoryRepository productCategoryRepository) {
    this.productRepository = productRepository;
    this.productCategoryRepository = productCategoryRepository;
}

@RequestMapping("/productsTable")
    public String showProductsTable(Model model){
        Iterable<Product> products = productRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("products", products);
        return "productsTable";
    }

@RequestMapping("/productsTableCategory")
    public String showProductsTable(Model model, @RequestParam int id) {
        ProductCategory productCategory = new ProductCategory();
        productCategory.setId(id);
        Iterable<Product> products = productRepository.findByProductCategory(productCategory);
        model.addAttribute("products", products);
        return "productsTable";
    }
```

Now it works almost perfect... almost because if I directly open `localhost:8080/productsTableCategory?id=1` for example I'll have my table sorted by given id. But when I try to open this by clicking 1 of links from my sidemenu, it isn't redirecting me anywhere

Comment: Just change your method like: `function changeClass(element) {
 $(element).siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
}`. All Done...! :)

Comment: isn't it should be `$('#sideMenu')`?

Comment: Actually soluton by Rohit works best, thanks!

Comment: Unofrtunatelly, I had to change this script to another one, which lead to another trouble I can't deal with. Edited my question with more info

Comment: Because you are using `preventDefault()` method in your code, so it will prevent the default action of the `a` tag..! Just remove the `preventDefault()` from your code and use the HTML5's `sessionStorage` to make the menu active..!

Comment: Sorry for dumb question but how exactly should I use `sessionStorage` to make this work? After removing `preventDefault()` it redirects to requested page, but it keeps changing active class to `allCategories` menu element

Comment: @user9309329..! Posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target anchor elements, excluding the current element i.e. `element` using the function [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/), then use `.removeClass()`. And use id selector with `sideMenu` element i.e. `#sideMenu`

```
function changeClass(element) {
    $('#sideMenu a').not(element).removeClass('active')
    $(element).toggleClass('active');
}
```

---

I would recommend you to use unobtrusive event handler and bind event using jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  method

```
$('#sideMenu a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sideMenu a').not(this).removeClass('active')
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

and remove `onclick="changeClass(this)"`

```js
$('#sideMenu a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#sideMenu a.active').not(this).removeClass('active')
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sideMenu" class=" vertical-menu">
  <a href="#" class="active">All</a>
  <a href="#">Fruits</a>
  <a href="#">Vegetables</a>
  <a href="#">Fish</a>
  <a href="#">Meats</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First remove the class active from the anchor.
2. Then add the class to the clicked element.

```js
$("#sideMenu a").click(function(e){

e.preventDefault();
$("#sideMenu a.active").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");

})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sideMenu" class="vertical-menu">
  <a href="#" id="allCategories" class="active">All</a>
  <a href="#" id="fruit">Fruits</a>
  <a href="#" id="vegetables">Vegetables</a>
  <a href="#" id="fish">Fish</a>
  <a href="#" id="meat">Meats</a>
</div>
```

Comment: this will always add `active` class not toggle

Comment: @Satpal `$("#sideMenu a").removeClass("active");` should remove the class from the anchor. then adding to clicked element

Comment: OP wants to toggle, re-read title of question and _I'm trying to toggle active class on click and remove it from another menu items_

Comment: @Satpal my understanding of toggle is adding and removing this will do even if not using the `.toggle()` method.

Comment: @Satpal it will remove the class from all anchor. Let me add a selector so it will select only the one with the class active

Comment: @Satpal not it will remove the class active from the anchor with the class active then add that class to the clicked element

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change selector in your code:

```
<script>
    function changeClass(element) {
        $('a').each(function(){        // Here a is used. It will loop through all anchor tags and apply the JQ.
            var theID = $(this).attr('id');
            var menuElement = document.getElementById(theID);
            menuElement.classList.remove('active')
        });

        $(element).toggleClass('active');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Check the comment for the change I made.

Answer (score 0):

In pure javascript you can do it like this.

```
<div id="sideMenu" class="vertical-menu">
    <a href="#" id="allCategories" class="active" >All</a>
    <a href="#" id="fruit" >Fruits</a>
    <a href="#" id="vegetables" >Vegetables</a>
    <a href="#" id="fish" >Fish</a>
    <a href="#" id="meat" >Meats</a>
</div>
```

and a js code.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('#sideMenu a');


// removes active class from all links
function removeAll() {
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
        links[i].className = '';
}

// adds active class to the clicked link, 
// but before it removes it from all other links
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', event => {
        removeAll();
        links[i].className = 'active';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may help you to make your menu active. Here `window.sessionStorage` is used..!

```
$("#sideMenu a").on('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem('activeMenu');
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('activeMenu', $(this).attr('href'));
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});

//check on redirected page (In your case productsTableCategory page)
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.sessionStorage.length > 0) {
        var menuToActive = window.sessionStorage.getItem('activeMenu');
        $("#sideMenu a.active").removeClass('active'); //comment this line to keep all menus active by default
        $('[href="' + menuToActive + '"]').addClass('active');
        window.sessionStorage.removeItem('activeMenu');
    } else {
        $('#allCategories').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: `$("#sideMenu a").addClass('active')` will work for the same...!

Comment: I thought so, but working with JS keeps suprising me. I removed `preventDefault()`, hoped it will keep `All` menu item selected (`active`) onbydefault, when page loads. It actually worked for a while, but now it is not. Page loads without anything `active` on menu, then if I click something it works like a charm, but I just can't make it active once page is loaded

Comment: Actually, I am unable to understand your scenario but edited my answer look again.

Comment: Or you can directly add the active class to all 'a' tags in HTML file to make them active default.

Comment: When I first enter `/productsTable` it displays all the products from my database and I'd like `<a href="/productsTable" id="allCategories" class="active">All</a>` to be active too by default. Right now when I load page, every link in menu is not `active`, they turn `active` when I click them and thats fine. But on top of that, when I enter the page by first time, I'd like this `allCategories` element to have `class = "active"` by default

Comment: Just place this code on your page..! `$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#allCategories').addClass('active');
});`

Comment: If I do that, it will be always stay active, even if I click on another link later, I'll have 2 links with `active` class. I just want `allCategories` be active by default when I load page or when I explicitly click on it.

Comment: Edited my answer again, you need to place your code inside else condition..!

Comment: I'v actually tried that, it still isn't working as I expect it to.